# Which one of the two does Gamma-Ray Astronomy most relate to: Physics or Chemistry?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astronomy, gamma-rays

So when I talk about [Gamma-Ray astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_astronomy), more specifically the following things:

1. Sources of Gamma Rays in the Universe and how they originate
2. Detection of Gamma Rays
3. Gamma Ray Bursts or GRBs
4. Composition of planets

, am I talking about Physics or Chemistry? That is to say, Gamma Ray Astronomy is a branch of Physics or Chemistry? Moreover, is the creation of gamma-rays studied under Nuclear physics or Nuclear chemistry?

Answer (score 1):

> [Gamma-ray astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_astronomy) is the astronomical observation of gamma rays, the most energetic form of electromagnetic radiation, with photon energies above 100 keV. Radiation below 100 keV is classified as X-rays and is the subject of X-ray astronomy.

All the terms in the definition are physics terms, as the terms in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Processes operating at gamma-ray energies do not allow to form any chemical bonds. Above a few tens of eV (i.e. already in the ultraviolet) all molecules dissociate into atoms, hence no chemistry is possible.

Nuclear chemistry doesn't exist as such (what would that be? Quark-Gluon interactions?), and furthermore astronomy is a field strongly related to physics, if you desperately need to categorize this.